# On Premise Network Share access through Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

Our On-premise AD and Azure AD are connected via AD connect. We want to join all our devices to Azure AD using Azure AD Join and we tested that, it is working. We have taken a Microsoft Intune license for that so that we can also manage the devices centrally, it has been deployed successfully.

Now we have an on-premise file share. We want to give user access to that file share while they are on move or on our remote site. We don't want to do the VPN between sites as there are only one or two users at the site who are accessing the file server. But there are a lot many users working remotely. We want to access that server via Azure AD join as I read it is possible to access on-premise resources with Azure AD joined devices. But it is not working for me. I tried all the solutions available on the internet including work folders, but there is no result.

Is it possible that file share can be accessible from the outside network using Azure AD join?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have plans to login to the AADJ device other than password method Like PIN/Bio-metric via WHFB credential login and then access on-premise resources (shares,printers..etc), check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business/access-resources?view=o365-worldwide)